# Magento2 extend layout from vendor folder

Tags: layout, magento2, extend

I have a module which has a visual output and therefore I like to extend an existing layout.

From what I read the magento2 way is to add a ne layout in `app/design/frontend` (according to http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html)

So my structure looks like this:

`app/code/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

`catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The content block is not changing in any way, so there seems either to be something missing or I have a missunderstanding here.
Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

My magento2 code is from https://www.magentocommerce.com/download so everything is placed in `vendor/`. Maybe that's why it is not working ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move this xml file to the following path : `app/design/frontend/<vendorName>/<themeName>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` and also, this theme must be activated in Backend.

Comment: I edited, please view again

Comment: so e.g

app/design/frontend/Unreal/Mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml  ?

or better 

app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer

Comment: I changed it to 
app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml  but it does not have any effect
In my themes I can see Magento/luma , so I seems to miss something still

Comment: You should add tag `<referenceContainer name="product.info.main" remove="true"/>` to check override

Comment: still the same.
I do not have other layouts in may app/design folder but everything else in /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml maybe there's an issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32350/discussion-between-christoph-ha-and-paw).