# override vendor xml file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, xml, vendor

Dears,

I have a xml file in the vendor directory:

```
vendor/the_vendor/the_module/view/frontend/layout/the_file.xml
```

I know that I should never make any change in this directory as it may be overrided by composer.
I also know that I should create the `the_file.xml` in my theme.

my theme path is:

```
app/design/frontend/the_Vendor/My_Theme/
```

Could you please let me know where the the_file.xml should be created (the exact path) in order to override the vendor xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way...

```
vendor/the_vendor/the_module/view/frontend/layout/the_file.xml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Themename/the_module/layout/the_file.xml
```

**Please don't forget to clear cache after change in xml files**

Comment: Upvoted question for marking answer as right for question.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at magento 2 documentation

Reference:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Comment: So I should always ignore the "view/frontend" ?

Comment: At first you need to decide: are you gonna extend or override the layout. There are some differences in paths. And a big difference in functionality. But if you build your own theme, in most cases there is enough to extend layouts rather than override them. Yes you need to skip view/frontend after vendor/theme in app folder. You have already set the frontend path in the design folder

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I created the following path inside my theme: Module_Name/layout/The_file.xml 

the file in vendor contains the following:

        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/> 
So in the theme i wrote: 

        <remove element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>

Comment: As per your actions inside the_file.xml I assume that you need to extend the layout. 

U can use this link as a reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92196/magento2-extend-layout-from-vendor-folder

Comment: And check please the way you removing the container

For example In checkout_cart_index.xml:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
That’s it.